# Getting Report Portal Error intermittently : Finish launch is not allowed and giving 'In Progress' status

Tags: reportportal

Getting error at last while using Report Portal. It's an intermittent issue. The execution is not getting completed in the report portal launch due to 'InProgress Status'. I have checked the following link issue. [Report Portal 406 execution error Issue](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/issues/126). I am not using any condition check in BeforeClass method and there is not Test Case still running after execution completed. Please find below the latest versions I am using:

1. com.epam.reportportal - agent-java-testng - 4.2.0
2. com.epam.reportportal - logger-java-logback - 4.0.0
3. com.epam.reportportal - client-java - 4.0.9

Points:

- I am using RP listener in Pom file.
- parallel="tests" thread-count="20"

```html
[2018-12-24 07:33:47.922] [ERROR] [com.epam.reportportal.service.Launch] : [76] ReportPortal execution error
com.epam.reportportal.exception.ReportPortalException: Report Portal returned error
Status code: 406
Status message: Not Acceptable
Error Message: Finish launch is not allowed. Launch '5c20fa81adbe1d00019c7763' has items '[5c20fa85adbe1d00019c7765]' with 'IN_PROGRESS' status
Error Type: FINISH_LAUNCH_NOT_ALLOWED

 at com.epam.reportportal.service.ReportPortalErrorHandler.handleError(ReportPortalErrorHandler.java:83)
 at com.epam.reportportal.service.ReportPortalErrorHandler.handle(ReportPortalErrorHandler.java:59)
 at com.epam.reportportal.restendpoint.http.HttpClientRestEndpoint$1.subscribe(HttpClientRestEndpoint.java:517)
 at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeCreate.subscribeActual(MaybeCreate.java:45)
 at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4096)
 at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeCache.subscribeActual(MaybeCache.java:77)
 at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4096)
 at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(MaybeSubscribeOn.java:54)
 at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:38)
 at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectTask.call(ScheduledDirectTask.java:26)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: @avarabyeu :  you are a contributor to report portal and your comments matter. So please take a look and let me know what could be done for the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is means that on the moment when ReportPortal receives event to finish Launch, it still has child (test case) in progress.

We will suppress this error in version 5.0, and leave as only warning.

**But the best approach:** (and as i see it worked for you)  find out why your tests are not finished on the moment, when testing engine finalize execution

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. There was some error with Driver initialization because of which it was getting interrupted to finish the launch.

Answer (score 0):

Because of tests are failing FINISHLAUNCH is not getting initiated.
Something like Nullpointer exeception or staleelement exception etc.

If we handle the errors in catch block then this issue can be resolved.